# Reinstalling windows, can I reuse the product key?

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 installed, which has a lot of bugs and I'm thinking to reinstall it from scratch. The recovery tool doesn't work either, so the only option that comes to my mind is to use a USB bootable key to reinstall Windows 8.1; but the problem is that it will probably ask me for the product key. Is there a way to reuse the old one?

Comment: Did this laptop come with Windows 8.1? Does it have a Windows Logo sticker?

Comment: @DanielB It has Windows 8 (not 8.1) already installed, but strangely it doesn't have the Windows logo sticker.

Comment: My mistake, it has the Windows 8 sticker, I didn't see it because it was on the back.

Comment: **ALL** Windows 8 and above devices have the license key loaded into firmware. While there are tools that can read the firmware and display the license key, it isn't a required step, the Windows 8 installer will automatically pick up the license key.  Edit your question to reflect it has Windows 8 installed, not Windows 8.1, otherwise you will get answers that don't apply to you.

Answer (score -1):

Definately, there are utils out there that will give you the product key (check HirensCD for example) but should also be on back of PC or under battery.

It is an OEM license for that PC, if you used it on another PC you may have trouble activating.

Might be worth looking at mini partition wizard tool to see what partitions you have (how many recovery).

Also look for an app on your current windows to create a media set, this usually requires 3 x DVD's and creates bootable install disks

Comment: The partitions won't affect licensing at all; OEM keys are bound to a serial number on the motherboard (usually).